# Can I use an existing database roles and users for a new or different MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When I start a new MVC project using individual user accounts, and perform my initial migration, the ASPNET roles/user tables are created. I know from experience with other projects that I can CRUD data in other existing tables in SQL by specifying the table in your model. However, is this case the same for the ASPNET Users and Roles tables? My hope is to have users who are registered in one of my applications to be registered in all of them with the same username and password.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415831/asp-net-identity-with-multiple-applications

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Every asp.net mvc project with authentication feature enabled contains a connection string definition with the name of "DefaultConnection" in Web.Config for the authentication database. It is shown below:

[image]

Now, what you have to do is to reference your authentication database in this connection string instead of the default connection string like:

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1;Database=YourAuthenticationDatabase;User Id=sa; Password=Abc;"
```