# How can multiple web apps be able to jointly use the same data from an identity database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

The question is really that how can an auth server that serves JWT be used by multiple websites of same company or domain (with the websites as sub-domains), for example? Not something for the public.

Already, I'm thinking of asymmetric JWT. Also, I don't want to implement OAuth 2.0 in order to avoid complexity and because the auth server would only serve web apps that are sub-domains of a same root domain.

Comment: You already asked this question and then deleted it.  Didn't you like the responses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity with multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415831/asp-net-identity-with-multiple-applications)

Comment: @nurdyguy Thank you for noticing that. I deleted that post because it was seemingly confused to be something about Single Sign-on...BUT I'm seeking for less complex solutions based on the current description in this post. I.e. a solution that involves connecting to a remote ASP.NET Identity database from various ASP.NET Web applications.

Comment: Yes. Web API supports both cookies and session support so you can place that layer over your security database and basically create a forms auth system that is single sign on between multiple apps.

Comment: So if a user logs in to one of the apps, are they then automatically authenticated on all of the other apps?

Comment: I see your update....  Doing that isn't merely just connecting to a single db from multiple sites.  It involves setting up the auth cookies for _all_ of the sites at once.  Take a look at what Win posted below.  It is probably more complex than you'd like but it is the _best_ way to handle this.

Comment: @nurdyguy As part of the process of a user logging in (unto the web apps) using a login form, the form uses Ajax to simultaneously submit a copy of the login details to each web app. On the server-side, each web app would then use the received login details to authenticate the user but by checking the details against the remote ASP.NET Identity SQL Server database. I just want to know if that is possible, because I would prefer it to other approaches, since each web app would be able to individually manage the shared remote ASP. NET Identity database.

Comment: I see three major problems here:  1.  The cookies returned would be attached to the _current_ url, not the url to which the ajax submitted.  2.  This feels like a giant security hole.  3.  Depending on exactly how many different sites are involved this could eventually be unsustainable.

Comment: You _might_ be able to do what you are describing using hidden iframes rather than ajax calls.  This could possibly solve #1 of my concern above but not #2 and #3.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks for your persistence. I just extended the question with some more updates which are well highlighted. Please, do give your opinion on them.

Answer (score 2):

> seeking for less complex solutions based on the current description in this post

If you want a reliable and secure way to share resources between different sites, you might want to look at [IdentityServer](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/).

In a nutshell, you basically redirect anonymous user to identity server to login. After successful login, it will return a token to the user. Then the user uses that token to access resources from different sites.

Look at the basic workflow and screenshots at [my GitHub sample project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/IdentityExample).

Comment: Using a separate identity server application is definitely the best way to handle this kind of thing.  Unfortunately I think it is a more complex answer than he is looking for.  It is what I would do though.

Comment: Well, tell your client that one should not create home-brew single-sign-on without proper knowledge and testing. It'll lead to a big security hole.

Comment: @Win Thanks for your post. Even though it is [or could be] a possible solution usable for me, I just updated my question in a highlighted form. Please do reconsider giving additional response(s) based on my updates.

Comment: Please, do check "UPDATE 2" of my question.

Comment: I just updated the post with update 3. Please do check it.

Comment: SO is not designed to answer like forum. If you keep adding questions to original post, then previous answers become obsolete and it becomes a mess. *If you have still have addition questions, please create a new one.*

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I had added some notes and classified my edits into numbered updates, so that readers can get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is the deal.

1. Can multiple web apps access the same database (identity db or otherwise)?  Of course!  Now if you are using Entity Framework (and I assume you are though it wasn't stated) then this can get tricky as far as migrations etc.  Personally I use Dapper so I never have to worry about that :-)

   Yes the apps can each access the db but that is ***WAY*** different from from SingleSignOn which is *really* what you are talking about.  You want a user to log in to one site and that identity to persist to other completely different sites.  That's not nearly as simple as simply accessing a db.  IdentityServer is virtually the standard for this kind of thing for many *reasons*.
2. No, the ajax approach will not work because when the user logs in at site1 the cookies are for site1.  If he goes to site2 the browser does not have any cookies associated with site2 even though you sent credentials via ajax.  The user was on site1 when this all happened so all cookies are site1 cookies, totally separate from site2 cookies.  Even if you can find a way to make this work it would pose a serious security risk.

   You could conceivably do something like this using hidden IFrames instead of ajax because you can set the iframe's site's cookies while you are there.  But I don't recommend you do this as there are security risks involved.

You need to separate the idea of "Authentication" from the ideas of "Authorization" and even "User Management".

Authentication----  Am I who I say I am?  (check my usename and password and maybe even additional form like text message etc)

Authorization----  Ok you know *who* I am, but what can I *do* on your site?  This can vary from site to site.  Maybe I am an admin on one of your sites but just a regular user on another.  My individual site cookies will includes roles etc and they are different for each site.

User Management----  Can I change my name/email/etc?

The best way to handle this is to use a separate server app running IdentityServer.  This handles the authentication and builds out the cookies for *all* of your sites at once.  Ideally you should also use this for any user management but that can be a pain and isn't as vital.  Here are a few sample apps for IdentityServer4.

---

Response to your Update 2----

Not exactly...  Here is the basic flow:  User goes to site1 and clicks "login".  This fires a "challenge" which redirects them to website-auth.  On website-auth the use submits their credentials (username/pw) via form post.  This logs them in to the website-auth but then also redirects the user back to the original calling app (site1 in this case) with everything they need.  Let's say the user now goes to site2, they are already logged in!!!  Using IdentityServer4, the user will become logged in to *all* of the sites sorta automatically.  You won't have to do extra stuff they way you described, just plug in the necessary stuff and let IdentityServer4 handle the rest.

Look, I understand that IdentityServer4 probably looks a bit intimidating, it did to me until I began working with it.  Truth is, all of the hard stuff is handled for you.  There is still a decent amount of configuration involved in getting it set up but it really is the best solution for what you are looking for.

Check out these quickstarts:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts

---

Response to Update3------

I understand the concern of relying on a third party and how that can seem like a questionable practice, especially when it comes to security.  My response is this:

1. These guys are *the **EXPERTS*** in the field.  So much so that IdentityServer has become the defacto security solution even in the basic templates Macrosoft provides.
2. Any home grown solution you will come up with will have more security holes that what IdentityServer has.  This is not a slight on you at all.  These guys know what they are doing.  They have been doing it for *years*.
3. Why reinvent the wheel?  You will spend 10x (at least) as many man-hours trying to come up with an alternative that, in the end, will still not be as good.

If what you were doing was a single website cookie based authentication then using identity really isn't necessary.  Identity can do that, but there are other simple alternatives.  But when it comes to multiple sites and SSO, and I really can't emphasize this enough, IdentityServer is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is obvious my thoughts about getting around CORS isn't realistic. I am still going to update the question with another update that would express a new workaround I thought about. And by "user managent", I meant what you meant, which is what it is, including the ability for an administrator, who is logged in on any of the web apps, to create user profiles, etc.

Comment: Please, do check "UPDATE 2" of my question.

Comment: Thanks again for your guidance. I had checked IdentityServer and it seems to be a paid solution, at some level, but I would check it the more, to see how much of it I can use for my purpose.

Comment: There are companies that do that kind of thing as a service but IdentityServer itself is open source and free.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the response. Btw, I just updated the post with an update 3. Please, do check it too.

Comment: Thank you for your response on my update 3. It has been an insightful discussion.

Comment: I edited the wrong answer. I don't know how to undo it.

Comment: @Olumide Don't worry, your edit was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a microservices auth serve that generates RSA/Asymmetric JWTs with a private key and the other servers each have the same counterpart public key to validate the JWT and retrieve the user claims.

But that solution doesn't not cater to the situation where each of those other servers need a different set of claims about about a user.

It is also not a single sign-on approach. So, I'll be back.

But OAuth 2.0 seems to be the answer, but it is too complex for my liking.

Comment: I unchecked as answer to review it due to having multiple login entry points. But aside for that, it's the closest to what answers my questions.